# git commit hooks - lifespan

Tags: git, githooks

I am using git commit hooks to kick off builds, do validations, etc.

What I would like to do is ensure the hooks get installed every time I check out an instance or copy of the git repository.

I am only aware of installing hooks by copying a file in the .git/hooks directory, but I'd like them to be permanently installed so I don't have to manually install them each time I do a git clone.  I always check my projects out to /tmp (ramdisk) and then push back to an actual disk once needed to reduce some I/O and increase speed.  Right now, my best solution is to have a script automate that process since my git hooks live in another repository anyways.

I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You can manipulate the [template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) (or configure it to point at a none-default template dir) so that the hooks are active/present in all new clones.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the way to go.

Comment: Another option to hooks would be [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) pulling your repository and then start everything from there. You wouldn't have to worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of my checkout / clone process, I make use of the template directory option rather than manually tarring contents.  This is a minor improvement, but helps me achieve better consistency.